# Which variable is set by `search-forward` in elisp?

Tags: elisp

In elisp to replace an occurrence of a string in a buffer I would do

```
(search-forward "aaa" nil 't)
(replace-match "bbb")
```

If between the search and the replace I modify the buffer, the following seems to happen:

`(match-end 1)` <- `(min (point-max) (match-end 1))`

`(match-beginning 1)` <- `(min (match-beginning 1) (match-end 1))`

Moreover if `(match-end 1)`==`(match-beginning 1)` `replace-match` calls insert at `(match-end 1)` (both of which gets updated to point to the end of the inserted string) whereas if `(match-end 1)`>`(match-beginning 1)` `replace-match` updates the string between `(match-beginning 1)` and `(match-end 1)` (and they get updated to point to the beginning and end of the inserted string)

So the second question is why the different behaviours?

Comment: If that's your second question, is your first question the title? The title doesn't appear to have any significant connection to the rest of the text. Don't post multiple questions together.

Comment: I guess it would be better to post it as "how is `replace-match` implemented"

Comment: If your text is representative of an actual use-case where the match data is getting corrupted and you want to prevent that happening, then there are functions such as `save-match-data` to cope with that sort of thing. `C-u C-h a match-data`. If you want to know the implementation details, you can always read the code.